# Sum of random variables decomposition

Tags: random-variable

Let $0< \delta<\frac{1}{2}$. Why do we have for $X_{1},X_{2}$ iid:

\begin{equation}
\{X_{1}+X_{2}>x\}\subset\{X_{1}>(1-\delta)x\}\cup\{X_{2}>(1-\delta)x\}\cup\{X_{1}> \delta x,\ X_{2}>\delta x\}?
\end{equation}

Comment: The result holds even when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are _not_ iid random variables.  Hint:  Sketch the plane with coordinate axes $X_1$ and $X_2$.  The first two sets are half-planes whose union covers all of the set $\{X_1 + X_2 > x\}$ except for a right triangular region with vertices $((1-\delta)x,\delta x), (\delta x, (1-\delta x))$, and $((1-\delta)x,(1-\delta)x)$. The third set $\{X_1 > \delta x, X_2 > \delta x\}$ is a quadrant that covers this triangular region.

Comment: I guess I didn't scroll down and see Henry's answer before writing my comment. But I do want to point out, in contrast to many questions here and on math.SE which fail to include assumptions such as iid that are necessary for solving the problem, here we have an explicit mention that the random variables are iid which is totally irrelevant to the question  which is about set inclusion without any hint of probability needed for its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to show $B^c\subseteq A^c$ instead of $A\subseteq B$, where $^c$ denotes the complement. In your case it suffices to show that
$$
\{X_1\leq (1-\delta)x\}\cap \{X_2\leq (1-\delta x)\}\cap \left(\{X_1\leq \delta x\}\cup \{X_2\leq \delta x\}\right)\subseteq \{X_1+X_2\leq x\}.
$$
Now take an $\omega$ belonging to the left hand side. Then $X_1(\omega)\leq (1-\delta)x$ and $X_2(\omega)\leq (1-\delta)x$ and either $X_1(\omega)\leq \delta x$ or $X_2(\omega)\leq \delta x$. Let us assume that $X_1(\omega)\leq \delta x$. Then
$$
X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega)\leq \delta x + (1-\delta)x = x,
$$
and hence $\omega$ belongs to the right hand side.

Answer (score 3):

As a visual demonstration

[image]

The yellow area (to the right of the rightmost green line), 
the blue area (above the higher green horizontal line), 
and the green area (above and to the right of the other two lines) 
together more than cover the dark area.

It will not work if $x \lt 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Just consider the case when $X_1<(1-\delta)x$ *and* $X_2<(1-\delta)x$, which means $(X_1,X_2)$ is not in the union of the two first sets. Then, if $X_1+X_2>x$, $X_1>x-X_2$ and, since $X_2<(1-\delta)x$,
$$
X_1 > x - (1-\delta)x = \delta x
$$
The same reasoning applies to $X_2$.

Comment: Simple proof. But $X_{2} < (1-\delta) x,\ X_{1}>\delta x$ doesn't obvious the point in $\{X_{1}> \delta x,\ X_{2}>\delta x\}$

Comment: @vinux: when $(X_1,X_2)$ is in the set $\{(X_1,X_2);X_1+X_2>x\}$, it is either in the union of the two first set or _not_. If _not_, I proved it is in the third set. QED!